# How to visualize similar resistance pattern in a plot using R

Tags: r, plot

I have a large dataset in which I want to group similar resistance patterns together. A plot to visualize similarity of resistance pattern is needed.

```
  
dat <- read.table(text="Id  Resistance.Pattern    
A   SSRRSSSSR     
B   SSSRSSSSR  
C   RRRRSSRRR 
D   SSSSSSSSS     
E   SSRSSSSSR  
F   SSSRRSSRR
G   SSSSR     
H   SSSSSSRRR    
I   RRSSRRRSS", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you provide any code you've written so far or an example of what your desired output should look like?

Comment: This question would benefit from details and focus. How do we interpret this 2-column data? Do you have an example of how you want this sample data to look in a plot? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I would separate out the values into a wider dataframe and then make a heatmap and dendrogram to compare sillimanites in patterns:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdendro)


recode_dat <- dat |>
  mutate(pat = str_split(Resistance.Pattern, "")) |>
  unnest_wider(pat, names_sep = "_") |>
  select(starts_with("pat_")) |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(. == "S" ~ 1, . == "R" ~ 2, is.na(.) ~0)))

rownames(recode_dat) <- dat$Id

dendro <- as.dendrogram(hclust(d = dist(x = scale(recode_dat))))
dendro_plot <- ggdendrogram(data = dendro, rotate = TRUE)


heatmap_plot <- dat |>
  mutate(pat = str_split(Resistance.Pattern, "")) |>
  unnest_wider(pat, names_sep = "_") |>
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("pat_"), names_to = "pattern_position") |>
  mutate(Id = factor(Id, levels = dat$Id[order.dendrogram(dendro)])) |>
  ggplot(aes(pattern_position, Id))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = \(x) sub(".*_(\\d+$)", "\\1", x))+
  theme(legend.position = "top")


cowplot::plot_grid(heatmap_plot, dendro_plot,nrow = 1, align = "h", axis = "tb")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the second column of your data frame represents sensitivity (S) and resistance (R), presumably to antibiotics (though this is not clear in your question). That being the case, you are presumably looking for something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- strsplit(dat$Resistance.Pattern, "")

do.call(rbind, lapply(p, \(x) c(x, rep(NA, max(lengths(p)) - length(x))))) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  cbind(Id = dat$Id) %>%
  mutate(Id = factor(Id, rev(Id))) %>%
  pivot_longer(V1:V9) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, Id, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(col = "white", size = 2) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#e02430", "#d8d848"), 
                    labels = c("Resistant", "Sensitive"),
                    na.value = "gray95") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Antibiotic", position = "top",
                   labels = 1:9) +
  labs(fill = "Resistance", y = "ID") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(text = element_text(color = "gray30"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate the entries by character, convert the binary data to numeric and plot the matrix as a `heatmap` and show the character string as rownames.

Whether to use a row and/or column clustering depends on whats desired.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  # for unnest_wider
library(gplots) # for heatmap.2

mm <- 
dat %>%
  group_by(Resistance.Pattern) %>%
  summarize(Id, Resistance.Pattern) %>%
  mutate(binary = strsplit(Resistance.Pattern, "")) %>%
  unnest_wider(binary, names_sep="") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("binary"), ~ as.numeric(c(R = 1, S = 0)[.x])))

mm2 <- as.matrix(mm[, -c(1,2)]) |> unname() # the numeric part

rownames(mm2) <- apply(as.matrix(mm[,1:2]), 1, paste, collapse=" ")

heatmap.2(mm2, trace="none", Colv="none", dendrogram="row", 
  col=c("green", "darkgreen"), margins=c(10,10))
```

[image: heatmap]